# Drawing dots problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose a person has a $0.2$ chance of drawing a red dot, a $0.4$ chance of drawing a blue dot, and a $0.4$ chance of drawing a green dot. If they draw a blue dot, they get a second chance to draw dots, in which they have a $0.5$ chance of drawing a second blue dot, and a $0.5$ chance of drawing a second green dot.

As the number of people $N$ that draw dots tends to infinity, what is the probability that a randomly picked dot is red/blue/green?

My intuition is: the expected number of red dots is $0.2N$, the expected number of blue dots is $0.4N + 0.4\times 0.5 N = 0.6N$, and the expected number of green dots is $0.4N + 0.4\times 0.5 N = 0.6N$.

This means the probability of a random dot being red should tend towards $\frac{0.2N}{0.2N + 0.6N + 0.6N} = \frac{1}{7}$, the probability of drawing a blue dot should tend towards $\frac{0.6N}{0.2N + 0.6N + 0.6N} = \frac{3}{7}$, and similar the probability of drawing a green dot tends towards $\frac{0.6N}{0.2N + 0.6N + 0.6N} = \frac{3}{7}$.

Is this intuition correct?

Answer (score 5):

**You intuition is correct.**  I'll outline a rigorous demonstration while avoiding technical details.

**We may describe this dot-drawing process as a *random walk.***  Specifically, let $t=0,1,2,\ldots$ enumerate the draws and after draw $t$ let $(R_t,G_t,B_t)$ count the numbers of red, green, and blue dots observed so far (respectively).  These are random variables equal to the sums of the results at each independent draw, which we might call $(dR,dG,dG)$ (known as the *increment* of the walk).

In this vector notation there are four possible outcomes of a draw, as tabulated here:

$$
\begin{array}{cc|rrr}
\text{Outcome} &\text{Probability} & {dR} & {dG} & {dB}\\
\hline
\text{R}&\frac{1}{5} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\text{BG}&\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\text{BB}&\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\text{G}&\frac{2}{5} & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

For example, the second line for the outcome BG (draw a B, then draw a G) corresponds to changing the vector $(R_t,G_t,B_t)$ to $$(R_{t+1},G_{t+1},B_{t+1}) = (R_t,G_t,B_t) + (dR,dG,dB) = (R_t,G_t,B_t) + (0,1,1),$$

which has a $2/5 \times 1/2 = 1/5$ chance of occurring.

From this perspective,

> **$(R_t,G_t,B_t)$ is the sum of $t$ independent versions of $(dR,dG,dB).$**

**From basic properties of the increment $(dR,dG,dB)$ we can deduce useful properties of the random vector $(R_t,G_t,B_t):$**

- The expectation is $t$ times the expectation of the increment, $$E[(R_t,G_t,B_t)] = tE[(dR,dG,dB)] = t\left(\frac{1}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{3}{5}\right).$$
- The variance is $t$ times the variance of the increment.  (We don't need to compute this, but merely need to observe the variance exists, is finite, and is proportional to $t$ due to the independence of the draws.)

Furthermore, the total number of dots $N_t = R_t+G_t+B_t$ lies between $t$ and $2t$ and therefore for $t\gt 0$ is strictly positive and no less than $R_t,$ $G_t,$ or $B_t.$  Consequently the fractions $R_t/N_t,$ $G_t/N_t,$ and $B_t/N_t$ (which are what the question asks about) are always defined, non-negative, and themselves have finite expectations and variances.

**These conditions imply the usual laws of large numbers, as well as the Central Limit Theorem, apply.**  The most basic conclusion is that as $t$ grows large, all quantities almost surely approach their expectations:

$$R_t \to \frac{t}{5},\ G_t \to \frac{3t}{5},\ B_t \to \frac{3t}{5},\ \text{and } N_t \to \frac{7t}{5}.$$

Finally, the preceding observations imply that the fractions $R_t/N_t$ *etc.* asymptotically approach the ratios of their expectations, which do not even vary with $t:$

$$\frac{R_t}{N_t} \to \frac{E[R_t]}{E[N_t]} = \frac{t/5}{7t/5} = \frac{1}{7},$$

*etc,* thereby formally justifying your intuition (and giving it a more rigorous basis).